# How can i replace particular word from a string with another expression(string) and the another expression has to get some part of particular word

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a String

```
String SQL="SELECT * FROM EMP(SELECT USERNAME FROM EMP WHERE EMPID=100 AND NULLIF(EXP1,EXP2) AND NVL(EXP1,EXP2) AND NVL(EXP3,EXP4)";
```

In the above String i have NVL(EXP1,EXP2),I want to replace this String with this string expression
**CASE WHEN EXP1 IS NULL THEN EXP2 WHEN EXP1== 0 THEN EXP2** where as EXP1 and EXP2 are arguments of the NVL(EXP1,EXP2),**this argument i want to get into the replacement String expression**.
I am using this RegExp to replace it

> Here is the Code

```
String SQL="SELECT * FROM EMP(SELECT USERNAME FROM EMP WHERE EMPID=100 AND NULLIF(EXP1,EXP2) AND NVL(EXP1,EXP2) AND NVL(EXP3,EXP4)";

  String Pattern   = "(?i)nvl\\(([^\\,)]+),([^\\),]+)\\)";

  String replacement = "CASE WHEN Temp1 IS NULL THEN Temp2 WHEN Temp1 == 0 THEN Temp2";

  SQL = SQL.replaceAll(Pattern, replacement);

  System.out.println(SQL);
```

> but Temp1 and Temp2 of replacement string i want to replace with EXP1 and EXP2 of NVL(EXP1,EXP2) because there will be number of NVL() functions with different arguments.

My Current output is :

```
SELECT * FROM EMP(SELECT USERNAME FROM EMP WHERE EMPID=100 AND NULLIF(EXP1,EXP2) AND CASE WHEN Temp1 IS NULL THEN Temp2 WHEN Temp1 == 0
 THEN Temp2 AND CASE WHEN Temp1 IS NULL THEN Temp2 WHEN Temp1 == 0 THEN Temp2
```

My expected out put :

```
SELECT * FROM EMP(SELECT USERNAME FROM EMP WHERE EMPID=100 AND NULLIF(EXP1,EXP2) AND CASE WHEN EXP1 IS NULL THEN EXP2 WHEN EXP1 == 0 
THEN EXP2 AND CASE WHEN EXP3 IS NULL THEN EXP4 WHEN EXP3 == 0 THEN EXP4;
```

Please help me out on this.I stuck here.

Comment: instead of using `replaceAll` take a look at regex classes `Pattern`, `Matcher` where you can have a Group replaced

Comment: @sidgate: how can i replace with the current string argument to the replacement string,Can you please provide some code sample for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manu's answer is pretty good, but I'd change it to use 'proper' regex group syntax, more like this:

```
String SQL = "...";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?i)nvl\\(([^\\,)]+),([^\\),]+)\\)");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(SQL);

String replacement = "CASE WHEN $1 IS NULL THEN $2 WHEN $1 == 0 THEN $2";
String s = matcher.replaceAll(replacement);
```

Here, the $1 and $2 are the groups, taken from your original regex pattern, which you want to use in your replacement.

The groups are specified by the brackets in your regex, just as Manu says, `$0` would give you the complete matched expression (i.e. `NVL(EXP1,EXP2);`), `$1` gives you the first expression enclosed in brackets (i.e. `EXP1`) and `$2` gives the second (`EXP2`).

Comment: Oh, this is easier indeed. Note that you'll need my solution if you want to do more string manipulation to the captured groups, as I needed recently :-)

Comment: @Davey:I have similar kind of requirement like I have function POSITION('STR' IN  STRING).I want know  the RegEx Pattern,which can give me this output:  INSTR(STRING,'STR'). Note that STR,It can be in single quote or double quote and the STRING should  be replace as it is from the POSITION function.STR and STRING is dynamic inputs from the user.

Comment: @sander, that seems like a different enough scenario to warrant a new question, plus as a question you'll be able to format it in a way that's clearer to read.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Pattern` and `Matcher`, you can use the captured groups in `replaceAll`:

```
String SQL = "...";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?i)nvl\\(([^\\,)]+),([^\\),]+)\\)");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(SQL);
if(matcher.find()) {
    SQL = matcher.replaceAll("CASE WHEN "
        + matcher.group(3) + " IS NULL THEN " + matcher.group(4)
        + " WHEN " + matcher.group(3)
        + "  == 0 THEN "
        + + matcher.group(4)); // TODO Not exactly what you want, edit it!
}
```

`matcher.group(0)` will be the entire expression, `matcher.group(1)` will be the first capture, etc.

I think you'll need `matcher.group(3)` and `matcher.group(4)` for this specific case, but I didn't test it.